# Where does NumberFormatInfo take its default NumberDecimalSeparator/NumberGroupSeparator characters from?

Tags: c#, localization

When creating a new `NumberFormatInfo` object, the `NumberDecimalSeparator`/`NumberGroupSeparator` characters should be the system's default, as per the documnetation ([1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numberdecimalseparator(v=vs.110).aspx), [2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numbergroupseparator(v=vs.110).aspx)):

> The initial value of this property is derived from the settings in the **Region and Language** item in Control Panel.

My language, formats, location and locale for non-Unicode are all set to Dutch/Netherlands, where `NumberDecimalSeparator` should be `,` and `NumberGroupSeparator` should be `.`, however when creating a new `NumberFormatInfo` object, the default values are reversed - `NumberDecimalSeparator` is `.` and `NumberGroupSeparator` is `,`.

Which system setting affects this?

Comment: In general you shouldn't create a new NumberFormatInfo but either use an existing one or clone an existing one and modify its properties, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo(v=vs.110).aspx#modifying. I guess when you create a new one, the one from InvariantCulture is used as default.

Answer (score 0):

The **CultureInfo.NumberFormat** helps you with the number formatting.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.numberformat?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_Globalization_CultureInfo_NumberFormat